# How to copy data from Excel to LWC lightning datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, excel

With the given requirement to allow users to paste content into multiple cells of a [LWC lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example), where the user has previously copied those values from an Excel sheet, what would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to capture a paste event, and then you can parse the data. Here's a [quick example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/cPHtLzSFjTwW3ZM4heP5/src/app.js?p=stories):

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} key-field="value">
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  data =  []
  // Avoid memory leaks
  _handler
  columns = []
  connectedCallback() {
    this._handler = (event) => this.handlePaste(event)
    document.addEventListener('paste', this._handler)
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    document.removeEventListener('paste', this._handler)
  }
  handlePaste(event) {
    let csvData = this.csvStringToArray(event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))
    this.columns = csvData.splice(0, 1)[0].map((value) => ({ fieldName: value, label: value }))
    this.data = csvData.map(row => row.reduce((p,v,i) => (p[this.columns[i].fieldName] = v, p), {}))
  }
  // Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991797/2132791, modified for tsv
  csvStringToArray(str) {
    var arr = [];
    var quote = false;
    for (var row = 0, col = 0, c = 0; c < str.length; c++) {
        var cc = str[c], nc = str[c+1];
        arr[row] = arr[row] || [];
        arr[row][col] = arr[row][col] || '';
        if (cc == '"' && quote && nc == '"') { arr[row][col] += cc; ++c; continue; }
        if (cc == '"') { quote = !quote; continue; }
        if (cc == '\t' && !quote) { ++col; continue; }
        if (cc == '\r' && nc == '\n' && !quote) { ++row; col = 0; ++c; continue; }
        if (cc == '\n' && !quote) { ++row; col = 0; continue; }
        if (cc == '\r' && !quote) { ++row; col = 0; continue; }
        arr[row][col] += cc;
    }
    return arr;
  }
}
```

This is a "full table" paste, assumes the first row are headers, may act weird if you reuse header column names. This is, of course, just one possible example, in order to help get you started.